# How to reset filter items in UI5 after page reload?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How to clear filter items of sap.m ViewSettingsDialog? Even though my table is getting refreshed , the filter option still displays my previous selected value?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct method available in `API` to clear filter item selection.

So, you can use following hook in your code:

```
 resetFilterItems: function() {
     var aFilterItems = this._oViewSettingsDialog.getFilterItems();

     aFilterItems.forEach(function(item) {
         var aItems = item.getItems();
         aItems.forEach(function(item) {
             item.setSelected(false);
         });
     });
 }
```

call `resetFilterItems` when your table is getting refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

As Ashish Patil mentioned in 2016 there is still no direct method available in API to clear filter item selection.

But there is an private method that can be used `_onClearFilters()`.

```js
this._oViewSettingsDialog._onClearFilters();
```

It will update/clear the selections, update counters and navigate to filter overview page if necessary.